# Is it possible to change the directory where Origen checks for sub-flows?

Tags: origen-sdk

The Origen test program generation [docs mention importing sub_flows](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/flows/#Re-usable_Flow_Snippets).  Is there a way to override where Origen searches for the sub-flow files?  In the examples, just the name of the sub-flow is passed to the import method, as so:

```
Flow.create(environment: :probe) do    
  import "vreg"    
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done in two ways.

1) Place the path in the flow file.  The downside of this method is the repetitive nature of the solution.

```
# 1)
Flow.create(environment: :probe) do
  import '../sub_flows/vreg'
end
```

2) Override the import method in your test interface.  This method solves the issue for everyone at once and cleans up the flow files.

```
# 2)
# Flow file
Flow.create(environment: :probe) do
  import 'vreg'
end

# Test interface file
def import(sub_flow, options = {})
  sub_flow = "../sub_flows/#{sub_flow}"
  super(sub_flow, options)
end
```